# Pandas dataframe to dict, while keeping duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
kenteken status code
0      XYZ      A  123
1      XYZ      B  456
2      ABC      C  789
```

And I want to convert it to a dictionary in a dictionary like this:

```
{'XYZ':{'code':'123', 'status':'A'}, {'code':'456', 'status':'B'}, 'ABC' : {'code':'789', 'status:'C'}}
```

The closest I've been able to come was the folling:

```
df.groupby('kenteken')['status', 'code'].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict()).to_dict()
```

Which yields:

```
{'ABC': {'status': {2: 'C'}, 'code': {2: '789'}},'XYZ': {'status': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'}, 'code': {0: '123', 1: '456'}}}
```

Which is close but not quite. I really don't know what to do anymore, so appreciate any help!

Comment: Does it have to be a dictionary? Take a look at `OrderedDict`. Maybe a list of tuples would be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I don't think it will be sufficient for the steps after it, but I'll give it a try** thanks!

Comment: df.to_dict(orient="records") gets you close.

Comment: Dictionaries can't have a key mapping with multiple values, which looks like what you want. However, you could have a key with a tuple of several values. Would that work? An example would be `{'XYZ': ({'code':'123', 'status':'A'}, {'code':'456', 'status':'B'})}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
a = dict(df.set_index('kenteken').groupby(level = 0).\
    apply(lambda x : x.to_dict(orient= 'records')))
```

print(a)

```
{'ABC': [{'status': 'C', 'code': 789}], 'XYZ': [{'status': 'A', 'code': 123}, {'status': 'B', 'code': 456}]}
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thanks so much :D

Comment: glad, it helped. btw, you can also give vote to answer :D

Comment: I tried, but my rep is too low so it won't be visible apparently(but still counts) ;)