# python: custom pandas.DataFrame to dictionary function: some entries are lost

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a `.xlsx` file, do some things with the data and convert it to a `dict` to save it in a `.json` file. To do that I use `Python3` and `pandas`.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

xls = pd.read_excel(
    io = "20codmun.xlsx",
    converters = {
        "CODAUTO" : str,
        "CPRO" : str,
        "CMUN" : str,
        "DC" : str
        }
    )

print(xls)
#print(xls.columns.values)

outDict = {}

print(len(xls["NOMBRE"])) # 8131 rows

for i in range(len(xls.index)):
    
    codauto = xls["CODAUTO"][i]
    cpro = xls["CPRO"][i]
    cmun = xls["CMUN"][i]
    dc = xls["DC"][i]
    aemetId = cpro + cmun
    
    outDict[xls["NOMBRE"][i]] = {
        "CODAUTO" : codauto,
        "CPRO" : cpro,
        "CMUN" : cmun,
        "DC" : dc,
        "AEMET_ID" : aemetId
        }

print(i) # 8130
print(len(outDict)) # 8114 entries, SOME ENTIRES ARE LOST!!!!!

#print(outDict["Petrer"])

with open("data.json", "w") as outFile:
    json.dump(outDict, outFile)
```

I add [here](https://www.ine.es/daco/daco42/codmun/codmunmapa.htm) the source of the `.xlsx` file (Spanish government). Select "Fichero con todas las provincias". You have to delete the first row.

As you can see, the `pandas.DataFrame` has 8131 rows, the `for` index at the end is 8130, but the length of the final `dict` is 8114, so some data is lost!

You can check that "Aljucén" is on the `.xlsx` file, but not in the `.json` one. Edit: Solved using `json.dump(outDict, outFile, ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: Is it possible that some names are repeated? If `xls["NOMBRE"][i]` has the same value for two different values of `i`, the second one will overwrite the first one. What do you get if you do `len(xls["NOMBRE"].unique())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have analyzed the file and seems like some "NOMBRE" values are duplicated. Try executing `xls["NOMBRE"].value_counts()` and you will see that for example "Sada" is twice. You will also see that the unique values are 8114 exactly.

As you are using the city name as the dictionary key, when the key is duplicated, you are modifying the previous value of the dict.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with gontxomde that if column "NOMBRE" has not only unique values, than it may lead to overwriting this key in the new dictionary.

To make a proof of concept I made a minimal example based on your approach:

```
import pandas as pd

feature_str = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame({"NOMBRE": [1, 1, 3], 
                   "CODAUTO": feature_str,
                   "CPRO" : feature_str,
                   "CMUN" : feature_str,
                   "DC" : feature_str
                   })
outDict = {}

print(len(df["NOMBRE"])) # 8131 rows

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    
    codauto = df["CODAUTO"][i]
    cpro = df["CPRO"][i]
    cmun = df["CMUN"][i]
    dc = df["DC"][i]
    aemetId = cpro + cmun
    
    outDict[df["NOMBRE"][i]] = {
        "CODAUTO" : codauto,
        "CPRO" : cpro,
        "CMUN" : cmun,
        "DC" : dc,
        "AEMET_ID" : aemetId
        }
print(outDict)
```

Which yields:

```
{1: {'CODAUTO': 'b', 'CPRO': 'b', 'CMUN': 'b', 'DC': 'b', 'AEMET_ID': 'bb'},
 3: {'CODAUTO': 'c', 'CPRO': 'c', 'CMUN': 'c', 'DC': 'c', 'AEMET_ID': 'cc'}}
```

If I could suggest, instead of iterating over the index of the DataFrame, it would be better to use DataFrame methods:

```
df.set_index("NOMBRE") \
  .to_dict(orient='index')
```

If you would use this in a dataset with unique values at NOMBRE, it would yield the same result, than the function you created. Additionally, in case you had duplicates it would raise an ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <module>
----> 1 df.set_index("NOMBRE").to_dict(orient='index')

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:1607, in DataFrame.to_dict(self, orient, into)
   1605 elif orient == "index":
   1606     if not self.index.is_unique:
-> 1607         raise ValueError("DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.")
   1608     return into_c(
   1609         (t[0], dict(zip(self.columns, t[1:])))
   1610         for t in self.itertuples(name=None)
   1611     )
   1613 else:

ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have duplicated values in `xls["NOMBRE"]`, each new duplicated will overwrite the previous one. So, you need to choose the strategy deal with duplicates, e.g. do you want different entries, like `Sada` and `Sada(2)`? Or do you want a single key `Sada` with the data from all the duplicates?

For the first example:

```
for i in range(len(xls.index)):

    # if it's the first time the value appears, just do the "normal" thing
    if xls["NOMBRE"][i] not in outDict.keys():
        outDict[xls["NOMBRE"][i]] = {
            "CODAUTO" : codauto,
            "CPRO" : cpro,
            "CMUN" : cmun,
            "DC" : dc,
            "AEMET_ID" : aemetId
            }

    # if the value was read before, add number of duplicate after the name
    else:
        for i in range(1, xls['NOMBRE'].value_counts()[xls["NOMBRE"][i]]):
            if xls["NOMBRE"][i] + '(' + str(i+1) + ')' not in outDict.keys():
                outDict[xls["NOMBRE"][i] + '(' + str(i+1) + ')'] = {
                    "CODAUTO" : codauto,
                    "CPRO" : cpro,
                    "CMUN" : cmun,
                    "DC" : dc,
                    "AEMET_ID" : aemetId
                    }
```

For the second case, there're good solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137903/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-dict-and-preserve-duplicated-indexes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244920/pandas-dataframe-to-dict-while-keeping-duplicate-rows).

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. However, I'm going to group the municipalities (`"Nombre"`) by their province, I think that by that way, there aren't going to be duplicated entries. If I find some issue, I will check again your answer.